# Declare a temporary variable or constant inside a closure that returns some View (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, dsl

I'm building a SwiftUI based view and I'd like to store a temporary value (so it can be used multiple times) in a closure that returns `some View`. The compiler is giving me the following error:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

```swift
struct GameView: View {
    @State private var cards = [
        Card(value: 100),
        Card(value: 20),
        Card(value: 80),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        MyListView(items: cards) { card in // Error is on this line, at the starting curly brace
            let label = label(for: card)
            return Text(label)
        }
    }
    
    func label(for card: Card) -> String {
        return "Card with value \(card.value)"
    }
}

struct MyListView<Item: Identifiable, ItemView: View>: View {
    let items: [Item]
    let content: (Item) -> ItemView
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                content(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Card: Identifiable {
    let value: Int
    let id = UUID()
}
```

If I inline the call to the `label(for:)` method, the build succeeds. Obviously, the example above is my simplified reproduction for the issue. In my actual app, I'm trying to store the return value of the method because it gets used more than once while creating the view for the individual item and that operation requires a potentially expensive evaluation in my model. It's wasteful to make that method call several times.

A couple notes:

- This `content` closure passed to `MyListView` is **not** a `@ViewBuilder`, but even if it was, I thought using a `let` as I've done should be okay.
- I'm not depending on the implicit `return` when a closure contains a single expression - I've added my own explicit `return`.
- It doesn't matter whether I use the declared variable or not. Just the presence of the statement upsets the compiler.

How can I write this so that I don't have to call the potentially expensive method more than once? Can someone explain what's happening at a language/syntax level to cause the error?

Comment: Do the work in a class that is an ObservableObject. Just have a variable label. The body get reloaded several times and the method will be called every time the body is called.

Comment: @loremipsum I don't think that will solve my problem. I'll just be calling into the ObservableObject several times and I'm trying to avoid that cost (this is what I meant by "that operation requires a potentially expensive evaluation in my model").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a limitation where the Swift compiler only tries to infer a closure's return type if it is a single expression. Closure's that are processed by a result builder, such as `@ViewBuilder`, are not subject to this limitation. **Importantly, this limitation also doesn't affect functions (only closures).**

I was able to make this work by moving the closure to a method inside the structure. Note: this is the same as @cluelessCoder's second solution, just excluding the `@ViewBuilder` attribute.

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State private var cards = [
        Card(value: 100),
        Card(value: 20),
        Card(value: 80),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        MyListView(items: cards, content: cardView)
    }
    
    func cardView(for card: Card) -> some View {
        let label = label(for: card) // only called once, and can be reused.
        return Text(label)
    }
    
    func label(for card: Card) -> String {
        return "Card with value \(card.value)"
    }
}
```

Thanks to @cluelessCoder. I would have never stumbled upon this discovery without their input and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately too complex for Swift to grasp, but there are several solutions:

First, you can manually declare what function it is:

```
MyListView(items: cards) { (card: Card) -> Text in 
            let label = label(for: card)
            return Text(label)
 }
```

Or you need to use the power of @ViewBuilder to make it work. Therefore, I have 2 working suggestions of equal quality

1. Using `Group`:

```
var body: some View {
        MyListView(items: cards) { card in
            Group {
                let label = label(for: card)
                Text(label)
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Using func with `@ViewBuilder` tag

```
@ViewBuilder func cardView(card: Card) -> some View {
        let label = label(for: card)
        Text(label)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        MyListView(items: cards, content: cardView)
    }
```

Additionally, you can simplify the second example and not use ViewBuilder, as you can manually say you will return Text, e.g.:

```
func cardView(card: Card) -> Text {
        let label = label(for: card)
        return Text(label)
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and they do work! Now I'm just stuck trying to understand _why_. Does this mean the`ViewBuilder` result builder is somehow more capable of using variables or inferring return types than ordinary Swift? I thought that `ViewBuilder`s were actually more restricted (limited support for control flow with just `switch`, `if let`, etc).

Comment: I also edited the post with examples without usage of ViewBuilder. What ViewBuilder helps is it “promises to return some View” and that’s why it works with him. Butas I showed in additional examples, if you tell the compiler what view to expect, it works as well. It’s because of the “too complex to infer type” kind of issue, I guess

Comment: PS: I’ve just tried and if you promise only Text in MyListView (and remove ItemView: View), your code compiles as well. - “let content: (Item) -> Text”… some View is not compiler friendly :-))

Comment: okay, that's helpful. i think this means Swift has less work to do in order to infer the return type of the closure (or function) when using `@ViewBuilder`, and inferring the type without `@ViewBuilder` is just too complex for the compiler. I find this really surprising and hard to believe. In the example in the question, the return type is just `Text`. There is no conditional branching so it will always be `Text`. How can just adding a `let ... = ...` increase the complexity so substantially? This might be a question for the compiler team on the Swift forums.

Comment: Here's a response (albeit a couple years old) confirming that the Swift compiler only tries to infer a closure's return type if it is a single expression (https://forums.swift.org/t/geometryreader-how-to-fix-unable-to-infer-complex-closure-return-type-add-explicit-type-to-disambiguate/27272/4).

Comment: Aha, good to know! Thank you